# Вывод слова из массива

Tags: python, массивы, python-3.x

Программа на шифр Виженера. Все выводит в конце выводит массив с буквами. Мне надо, чтобы эти буквы выводились как слово.
Т.е `[ a , c , d]` выводилась как `acd`

```
import string
import itertools
alphabet = {i[1]: i[0] for i in enumerate(string.ascii_letters)}
print(alphabet)
field_pow = len(alphabet)
a = input('Введите текст: ')
b = input('Введите ключ: ')
lst_a = []
lst_b = []
for i in a:
    lst_a.append(alphabet.get(i))
for i in b:
    lst_b.append(alphabet.get(i))
d = lst_b * len(a)
newarray=d[0:len(a)]
u = [x + y for x, y in itertools.zip_longest(lst_a, newarray, fillvalue=0)]
s = [key for key, value in alphabet.items() if value in u]
print(s)
```

Answer (score 3):

Поменяйте последнюю строчку кода на `print(''.join(s))`

Comment: Спасибо!!Помогли. А то чет затупил

Comment: Бывает. Закройте вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

Поменяйте последнюю строчку кода на:

```
print(*s, sep="")
```

так при больших s быстрее.